# Get pointer to 1st element of std::list

Tags: c++, list, vector, std

Here I have simple code, it works for std::vector, but don't work for std::list.

Is it wrong because elements in list doesn't alighned?

**Edit:**

Ok, what is the best way to put list in func? Convert it to vector?

for example I need it when put data in [PolyPolyLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162819%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

vector<int> func(int* buf)
{
    vector<int> t;
    t.push_back(buf[0]);
    t.push_back(buf[1]);

    return t;
}

int main() {

    list<int> ls;
    vector<int> v;
    ls.push_back(2);
    ls.push_back(111111);
    v.push_back(12);
    v.push_back(11);

    vector<int> t1= func(&v[0]);
    vector<int> t2= func(&ls.front());

    cout<<t1[0]<<t1[1];
    cout<<t2[0]<<t2[1];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/1RFAe3 here is online compiler to test.

Comment: `vector`'s memory is contiguous, `list` is not. So you cannot play pointer arithmetic games like this. You should use an iterator and increment/decrement the iterator.

Comment: In other words, using `&front()` to get a pointer to the first element is fine. But using `&front() + 1` to get a pointer to the *second* element (which is what the code above amounts to) is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `std::list<T>` is a linked list, so its memory is not contiguous. You cannot use regular pointers with it to do pointer arithmetic - it's undefined behavior.

If you change your program to take iterators instead, and use `std::next` to access elements beyond the current one, your program would produce the behavior that you expect.

```
template <typename T>
vector<int> func(T buf)
{
    vector<int> t;
    t.push_back(*next(buf, 0));
    t.push_back(*next(buf, 1));

    return t;
}
...
vector<int> t1= func(v.begin());
vector<int> t2= func(ls.begin());
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/hYIF75)

Answer (score 3):

You can't take the address of an item in a list and use it as an array.  std::list is a doubly linked list with dynamically allocated nodes.  Unlike a vector, the elements in the list are not contiguous.

Answer (score 3):

The only container that guarantees continuous memory allocation is `std::vector` (and `std::array`). You don't have any sort of guarantee like that with a `std::list`, which is why this approach can't possibly work.